# how to put google+ sign-in code inside a different java source file

Tags: android, fragment, google-plus

I've a class `MainActivity` in which I'm implementing tabs+swipe navigation.
I'm creating different java files for the different fragnents. But the problem is I won't be able to access the values of the variables in `MainActivity` class.
Right now I've put the fragment class inside the `MainActivity` class and the app is working fine. How to accomplish the same result if want to create separate java file for separate fragments. This is my fagment class for now :

```
public static class fragmentLeft extends Fragment{
    public fragmentLeft(){} 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left,
                container, false);
        View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //mChronometer.start();

                if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sadf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                        mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            // Try connecting again.
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),(CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mConnectionResult = null;
                            mPlusClient.connect();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

These are the variables which are present in the `MainActivity` class that I want to access from the fragment class :

```
private static ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
private static PlusClient mPlusClient;
private static ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and it is not clear to me exactly what you are looking for. However, what you are seeking to do is relatively straightforward. Take a look at this example (which relates to Google Play Game Services and is rather more complex than what you are seeking to achieve):

[Google Play Game Services Multi-Player Device Orietation change kicks user out of room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594102/google-play-game-services-multi-player-device-orietation-change-kicks-user-out-o/17699846#17699846)

There are various ways of accessing variables in different fragments and the "recommended" way is probably to implement a listener interface. I often use a simpler approach based on calling a method in a fragment from the activity like this :

```
    myFrag fragment = (myFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFrag");
    fragment.someMethod();
```

Another simple approach is to use shared preferences to access the variables directly.

Comment: I edited the question. And I want to access these things from my fragment class.