# Using isSignedIn in onCreate? [Google Play Service]

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my application i want to let users sign in with their google account so i am using google play services. This works -  they can login and logout. I also want to find out if the user is signed in the **onCreate** method when i pass from one activity to another. I am trying to use Google play services isSignedIn function for this but on **onCreate** method it always return false (because google play service trigger on **onStart**).

**Why do I want it ?**

Because, i have two login option. One is google account another is my own login panel. I want to know that is user sign in wtih google or my system or not on **onCreate**. So i will give direction my flow.

How can i achive this or do you have an alternative suggestion ?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the Activity lifecycle. Every time an Activity goes into the background, it will get `onStop`. The Play Games API requires you to disconnect when this happens. When the Activity comes back into the foreground, it gets `onStart`, and then GameHelper will attempt to reestablish the connection. Until this happens, `isSignedIn` will return `false`. When the connection is restored (which should be very fast if the user had already signed in), the `onSignInSucceeded` callback will be called and from that point on `isSignedIn` will return `true`.

It's impossible to know, on `onCreate`, whether or not the sign-in will succeed. Instead, you should wait for either `onSignInSucceeded` or `onSignInFailed`. It is guaranteed that one of those two callbacks will be called shortly after the Activity comes into the foreground.

At that point, you can decide what to do, because it will be clear whether or not the user is signed in with Google+.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain how your app works but it sounds as though you may be calling GameHelper.onStop at the end of one activity when in fact you want the game to continue in another activity. I don't think you can do this (see the accepted answer here):
[Google Play Game Services multiplayer with Activity switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726100/google-play-game-services-multiplayer-with-activity-switching)

My app is arranged into fragments and I have one fragment which interacts with GameHelper. Therefore, once I have performed GameHelper.setup and GameHelper.onStart, I am able to call isSignedIn from any method in any fragment and get the correct response.

An alternative approach (which I have used in the past) is to save the result of isSignedIn in a boolean in shared preferences. You can then check this to determine whether the user is signed in or not.