# How to properly implement manual sign in option with Android Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would like to implement Google Play Services in my android application, but I don't want application to ask user to sign in, when the applications starts for the first time, so I've used the following code in my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (prefs.getBoolean("pref_user_game_enabled", false) == false) {
      getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0); 
    }
    ...
```

and I've implemented [manual sign in](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin), when user presses the button in the separate `GameSignInActivity`:

```
public class GameSignInActivity extends BaseGameActivity 
  implements View.OnClickListener {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0); 
    findViewById(R.id.game_signin_btn_signin).setOnClickListener(this);
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.game_signin_btn_signin) {
        getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(3);
        beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.game_signin_btn_signout) {
        signOut();

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("pref_user_game_enabled", false);
        edit.commit();                  
    }
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("pref_user_game_enabled", true);
    edit.commit();      
}
```

Let's say user ran my app, signed in to Google Play, closed the app and now runs it again. How can I know that user is already signed before? `isSignedIn()` at `MainActivity` returns `false`. And what should I do to be able to use Google Play Services API there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling *isSignedIn()* in *onCreate()*?
You should wait for *onSignInSucceeded()* to get signed in. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064376/2176708

Comment: Yes, I call it there.