# Single 'activity' for Google Play services in iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, google-play

When writing android apps that take advantage of google play services, I use fragments inside the same activity when switching view so I can stay connected to the play services at all times.  In order to update high scores and unlock achievements, I was told this is best practice, and it has worked well for me so far.

I'm beginning to 'translate' some of my games over to Xcode but I have very little experience with iOS in general.  Before I start building a big UI, do I need to keep everything encapsulated in a single view to take advantage of Play services? Or can I use tabbed viewControllers and built in UINavigationControllers to move between views and still stay connected.

Answer (score 0):

probably should use tabbed view controllers built in.  [From this question and answer, with bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726100/google-play-game-services-multiplayer-with-activity-switching), it looks like you must instantiate the google play services from the single activity and initiate from there.